# My numpy arrays are behaving weirdly in cython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

Okay so I followed the instructions on the Cython docs to get numpy arrays to be recognized by cython. Here is the "preamble" of my script

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np 
cimport numpy as np 

DTYPE = np.int 
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
```

I'll be honest, I'm not sure exactly what the line `ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t` does, simply because i'm not sure why there's the suffix `_t`. However it seems to handle the numpy arrays fine now so I'm not complaining. Now the problem lies herein:

I have two files called cell_spks and cell_dirs. These are both text files, for which I posted a gist of both [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7793114) and [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7793091) respectively. As you can see they're just 5x8 arrays of numbers. The problem is now when I load these in and try to do manipulations it just WONT work. [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7793721)'s a gist of my code (warning, its pretty long) and [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7793674) is my setup file. Now I did not write the big functions, and in fact this is only a snippet of my actual computations, but this is where my  error lies so I'm only posting this section. In essence, I need the platemethod function however calling the platemethod function gives me an error  "TypeError: Cannot convert numpy.int64 to numpy.ndarray". I'm not sure what's going wrong, why would it try to convert it in the first place?? I'm sorry if this is a rather large question guys.

EDIT: I should mention this function used to be a python script, I "translated" it to cython (to the best of my abilities)

Comment: `ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t` just creates an alias to `np.int_t`, a type that is meaningful within C. When something is cdef'd you should declare it using such a type. You don't need to use the pair of lines above; you can replace every instance of `DTYPE_t` with `np.int_p` and `DTYPE` with `np.int` (which is a python object).

Comment: Can you post some more of the traceback? Specifically, on what line are you getting that error?

Comment: @HenryGomersall Sorry I took long to answer back. [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7810671) is what it spits out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have defined `IX` (and `IY` and `IXY` and ...) to be type `np.ndarray` on line 99. The point about Cython is that you can assign variables to be statically typed, which you do with a cdef, which you have done in those cases. Given the variable is of type `np.ndarray`, you can't then assign another type to it.

`sum(IX)` sums along the array and, in this case, returns an object of type `numpy.int64`, which can't be assigned to `IX`. You'll need to use a different variable name, which can either be cdef'd (and statically typed) or just a normal python object.